# Java stack queue palindrome

Tags: java, stack, queue, palindrome

I am using stack and queue to check if a string is palindrome. My code works fine for "Anna", "Level", but it doesn't work for "A nut for a jar of tuna!". I wish someone could help me

```
    public boolean isPalindrome(String item) {
        clearData();

        String s = item.replaceAll("[\\W]", "");
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            stack.push(s.substring(i, i+1).toLowerCase());
            queue.enqueue(s.substring(i, i+1).toLowerCase());
        }

        while (! stack.empty() && ! queue.empty()) {
            if (! stack.pop().equals(queue.dequeue())) {
                return false;
            }
        }


        if (!stack.empty() || ! queue.empty())
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: `!` is not a whitespace character.  You also need to trim out punctuation.

Comment: Also, instead of storing STrings of 1 character, you could just store characters.

Comment: I did trim out all punctuation by using item.repaceAll("[\\W]", "") which trims both whitespace and punctuation

Comment: Without seeing how `stack`, `queue`, and `clearData` are defined, and seeing your main program, we can't try this ourselves.  There's nothing obviously wrong, assuming that the stack and queue methods do what we think they should.  But we can't tell.  Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As already suggested: post [mcve]. Don't make us guess.